# How can I code the query set in order that the users can see only their own post in profile section

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-2.0

I'm working on a project by using Django 2.06. I have multiple users and they can post and other people can read their post which is very normal. At the user profile page User should see their own post.
this is where I'm stuck, How i can code the queryset then at the profile section user can see only their own post.

**code demo**

```
class ProfileView(ListView):

    template_name = "profile.html"
    queryset = QuickWord.objects.filter()
    context_object_name = 'quickword'


    def get_context_data(self, **Kwargs):
        context = super(ProfileView, self).get_context_data(**Kwargs)
        context['addproduct'] = AddProduct.objects.filter()
        context['article_view'] = Article.objects.filter()
        context['edit'] = Profile.objects.all().last()
        return context
```

I know that I have to use filter value but do not know how to do that.

Thanks

Comment: How does your `Article` model looks like? How do you store what user wrote what post?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your have an `author` field in your `Post` model, You should do something like this in your `views.py`

```
def profile(request):
    user_posts = Post.objects.filter(author=request.user)

    return render(request, 'path/to/profile.html', {'posts': user_posts})
```

Of course the above view requires the user to be logged in.